# IOS Audio stops playing when screen goes off in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

Hi am new to IOS and Swift.

I am making an app which contain two audio files which plays on the second `ViewController`. I use Navigation controller and `push` to go to the second `ViewController`. As I found when going back to the first `ViewController`, the audio will not stop, I used this code :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    audioPlaying.stop()
}
```

Now the audio stops when going back, But also audio will stop if screen goes off means when application is locked or in background,
How can I get rid of this?

More code :

```
var audioPlaying = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    audioPlaying = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audioOne", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        audioPlaying.stop()
}
@IBAction func playPause(sender: AnyObject) {
    if buttonLabelChange == true {
        let image = UIImage(named: "btn_pause.png") as UIImage?
        playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonLabelChange = false
        audioPlaying.play()
    }else{
        let image = UIImage(named: "btn_play.png") as UIImage?
        playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonLabelChange = true
        audioPlaying.stop()
    }
}

@IBAction func sliderAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    audioPlaying.stop()
    audioPlaying.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(sliderOutlet.value)
    audioPlaying.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlaying.play()
    let image = UIImage(named: "btn_pause.png") as UIImage?
    playPauseButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonLabelChange = false
}
```

Comment: can you upload more code about your audio player and what did you mean by screen goes off?

Comment: screen goes off, means automatically lock the device or on locking the device lock.

Comment: @Ishu Both automatically locking and locking.

Comment: You have to register you app for background execution. See the [Background Execution Document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the method `isMovingFromParentViewController`?

The method returns `true` when the view is popped, but `false` when the phone locks.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        if self.isMovingFromParentViewController()
        {
                audioPlaying.stop()
        }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer with another method (isMovingFromParentView instead of isMovingToParentView) and checked it, and works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using it in deinit method. Hope this helps!!

```
deinit {

    if (audioPlayer.playing){
    audioPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do one thing register notification of the applicationWillResignActive in your view  and when application is locked it goes in that methods and it stop the audioplayer.

1) put this code in viewDidLoad()

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"in-the-storm" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: @KingsProgrammer please check my edited answer. May this help you.

Comment: shah thanks for your answer :)
still not working, this is also stoping the audio, what I want is : even when the screen is locked the audio should be playing.

Comment: try to used AVAudioSession for background play

Comment: i edit my answer but it is in objective c and i think it is easily convert in swift

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default  navigation back button add your custom button with action.

//Hide Navigation bar - Add this code in your viewdidload(FirstViewController)

self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;

in the second view controller

@IBAction func popView (sender:AnyObject)
    {

```
   audioPlaying.stop()
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true);

}
```